# jQuery AJAX - What's the deal with cached data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, get

In this [jQuery AJAX w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp), the website said:

> **Note:** The GET method may return cached data.

What's the deal with *cached data*? Is it not secure because the data is stored on the computer?

I looked at several other site, but I didn't find the answer. Maybe because I still don't understand about the idea behind *cached data*.

I hope someone can explain the *shallow* version before going into the *deep* version for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

By default (with some caveats) jQuery will cache AJAX requests made using GET or HEAD in an in-memory object, keyed by the URL which was requested.

If you do not wish to have the request cached, set `cache: false` in the AJAX settings prior to making the request. You can learn more about this in the [documentation for `$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Also note that W3Schools articles are notorious for being vague, misleading, outdated or just downright wrong. I would strongly suggest you stop using them as a resource.

For referencing jQuery information, the official [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/) is far more accurate, while for JS, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) is the best resource to use.